# TypeError, admin.firestore(…).collection(…).doc(…).collection(…).doc(…).get.then is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to code a function that triggers when a user gets a new comment and sends a notification.Comments are stored in /Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}. Users save their device notification tokens to /users/{userID}

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotif = functions.firestore.document('Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((change,context) =>
{
    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(user_id).collection('Notifications').document(notification_id).get().then(queryResult=>{

      const from_user_id = queryResult.data().From;

      const from_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(from_user_id).get();
      const to_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(user_id).get();

      return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {

        const from_name = result[0].data().From;
        const to_name = result[1].data().From;

        console.log("FROM: " + from_name + "TO: " + to_name);

      });

    });

});
```

And here's the package.json file. Everything is up-to-date

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Firebase gives the following error:

```
TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).document is not a function
    at exports.sendNotif.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:13:50)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:768:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: As the error says you are using `document` instead of `doc`.

Comment: *****Thanks****

Answer (score 0):

[`admin.firestore().collection(...)`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Firestore#collection) returns a [CollectionReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/CollectionReference) object.  As you can see from the linked API docs, there is no method called document() on that.  But there is a [doc()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/CollectionReference#doc) method.  Use that instead.

Comment: Now i have a different problem,  it says...TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
    at Promise.all.then.result (/user_code/index.js:22:43)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: That sounds like a different question.

Comment: Code is same. In my firestore I have this structure Users/user_id/Notifications/notification_id... in this i have different fields  from,from_ID,name,etc and I am getting this error.....TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined at Promise.all.then.result (/user_code/index.js:22:43) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: Because that has been solved after the answer given by you :)

Comment: Please help me out, I'm new to firebase :(